# converting unsigned char in c++ to java

Tags: java, c++

I have an unsigned char in C++ that is below.

```
unsigned char key[264] = {
    0x2b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xda, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x58, 0x24, 0x32, 0x6a, 0xc3, 0x06, 0x1b, 0x2c,
    0x6b, 0x61, 0x3e, 0xaf, 0xec, 0x31, 0x60, 0x38, 0x05, 0x46, 0x04, 0x0c, 0x2b, 0xb9, 0x6e, 0x2e,
    0x07, 0x5d, 0xff, 0xe8, 0x64, 0xe3, 0x70, 0x40, 0xdb, 0x93, 0xda, 0xcc, 0x01, 0x18, 0x22, 0x5e,
    0xdf, 0x94, 0x5a, 0x4f, 0x25, 0xbe, 0x1d, 0xb5, 0x4b, 0xb4, 0x17, 0x8b, 0xf4, 0x57, 0x39, 0xb3,
    0xfe, 0x91, 0x63, 0x7d, 0x1c, 0x9f, 0x7a, 0xca, 0x3a, 0x1e, 0x65, 0xa7, 0x68, 0xd1, 0x89, 0x78,
    0x67, 0x43, 0xf3, 0xb2, 0x8d, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x9e, 0x9c, 0xc9, 0xe9, 0x9b, 0xb6, 0xba, 0x75, 0x20,
    0x74, 0xd3, 0x3f, 0x88, 0x56, 0x6d, 0x41, 0x62, 0x2a, 0xc6, 0xa2, 0xc5, 0x5f, 0x7b, 0x33, 0xc4,
    0xf6, 0x3b, 0xef, 0x97, 0x95, 0x92, 0x87, 0xc7, 0xf7, 0x52, 0x7f, 0x10, 0xa8, 0xdc, 0x45, 0xd0,
    0xfd, 0x99, 0x9d, 0xe0, 0x0e, 0x29, 0x6c, 0x81, 0x83, 0xd5, 0xe7, 0xee, 0xfa, 0x59, 0xa9, 0x27,
    0x26, 0xcd, 0xdd, 0xae, 0x09, 0x44, 0x30, 0x47, 0xe5, 0xf0, 0x37, 0x5b, 0x13, 0x4a, 0x96, 0x4e,
    0x72, 0xa6, 0x79, 0xd4, 0xa4, 0x98, 0x36, 0xe6, 0x86, 0xd7, 0x28, 0x02, 0xf9, 0x2d, 0xbc, 0x12,
    0xed, 0xbf, 0xad, 0x48, 0xce, 0x84, 0x82, 0x7c, 0xfb, 0x53, 0xe2, 0xea, 0x0d, 0x14, 0x1f, 0x54,
    0xaa, 0x08, 0x23, 0xf2, 0x21, 0x4c, 0x8c, 0x3d, 0xbd, 0xa1, 0x35, 0xb7, 0x55, 0x42, 0x4d, 0xa5,
    0x8f, 0x3c, 0x85, 0xc8, 0x77, 0x03, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x11, 0x15, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xb1, 0xeb, 0x5c, 0x71,
    0xd8, 0xc2, 0x8a, 0x0f, 0x76, 0x50, 0xa0, 0x19, 0x73, 0xf5, 0xfc, 0x0b, 0x69, 0xe1, 0x90, 0xd2,
    0xab, 0xc1, 0x9a, 0x51, 0x6f, 0x34, 0x80, 0xb8, 0xa3, 0xd6, 0xcb, 0xe4, 0xcf, 0x2f, 0xf8, 0xbb,
    0x16, 0x66, 0xb0, 0x49, 0xac, 0xde, 0xf1, 0x7e
};
```

What would the java equivalent be in bytes?

I tried:

```
byte[]key = new byte[264] = {
    .....
}
```

but that didn't work. It gave me errors at the line I changed.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know Java, but I'm pretty sure it would help at least a tiny bit to know WHAT errors you get...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `byte` in Java is *signed*, so it can only store values from -128 to 127.
You can treat it as unsigned though, if you take some precautions. These precautions mainly have to do with the automatic conversion to `int` (Java's 32-bit signed datatype).

Because of it's range, it not valid to assign values above 127 to it. Integer literals in Java have the type `int`, but in assignments to a byte, they get implicitly converted to the type byte. But not if the value is higher than 127. You can still force it to convert though, by casting. The first value higher than 127 (`0x7f`) is `0xda`; write `(byte)0xda` and things will work:

```
byte[] key = { 0x2b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xda, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x58, 0x24, 0x32, 0x6a, (byte) 0xc3, 0x06, 0x1b, 0x2c,
```

etc.

Comment: I'm not sure which would be higher than 127 though :(

Comment: All the ones that give you an error. If you have an IDE like Eclipse they're underlined or highlighted. Put `(byte)` in front of them. If you can't find out, then put it in front of every value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] key = {...};
```

or

```
byte[] key; 
key = new byte[] {
 ...
};
```

Comment: 100 errors: ` error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte`

Comment: Make type of constants explicit: byte[] key = {(byte)0x00, ...}